# How to correctly implement Single Log Out in Azure AD B2C for SPA's?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

**Scenario:**

We have 2 SPA's built using Angular. Both of them use OIDC and custom policies. We are trying to get Single Log Out to work smoothly. Till now, we have managed to get it working partially. We have followed the steps provided here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003445#single-sign-out

**Steps**

- User logs in to App A in a browser tab.
- User accesses App B in a different browser tab and is automatically logged in (expected behaviour).
- User logs out of App B.
- User comes back to the browser tab with App A open. If the user refreshes the application, the user is logged out. However, if the user does not refresh the application, the user is still logged in. We have validated that the user's session data is cleared from App A.

Is it possible to have a seamless experience here, so that the user does not have to refresh the application to be logged out?

**Note** - While doing the configuration for this, we came across this thread - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1057477/how-to-implement-single-sign-out-in-azure-ad-b2c-u.html. This is a bit confusing since the answer provided here states that the Front-Channel Logout URL should be this - https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<your-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<PolicyName>/oauth2/v2.0/logout. However the text in the Azure Portal states that this where a request is sent to have the application clear the user's session data, implying that this should be an application URL. The OIDC specifications also imply the same thing. We have currently configured this with an application URL.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function `useIsAuthenticated()` to check if the user is still authenticated you can set that in your layout file to provide access to your application.

It returns a boolean value so if it's false you can redirect to login page.